# fixed width in gxt grid

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

guys i want to fix certain column width ... i want to use setFixed(true)  ... here how i create the column

```
  private ColumnConfig<ContentAttribute, ContentAttribute> createActionsColumn(int actionsColumnWidth) {
final BackofficeButtonCompositeCell<ContentAttribute> buttonsCell = new BackofficeButtonCompositeCell<ContentAttribute>(
    createActionsGridCellRenderer().getButtonsCells());
final DtoValueProvider<ContentAttribute> valueProvider = new DtoValueProvider<ContentAttribute>(ACTIONS_COLUMN_ID);
return SenchaGridUtils.createDefaultColumnConfig(valueProvider, actionsColumnWidth, MessagesFactory.bo().actions(),
    buttonsCell);
```

}

then how to fix its width ??

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesnt appear"? Its width is not fixed or the column doesn't appear at all?

Comment: i mean where to use it

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
ColumnConfig columnConfig = SenchaGridUtils.createDefaultColumnConfig(valueProvider, actionsColumnWidth, MessagesFactory.bo().actions(), buttonsCell);
columnConfig.setFixed(true);
return columnConfig;
```